# Cannot pass variable to form

Tags: yii

Im trying to do something very simple, which I have done countless times before - pass a variable to a view which contains a form. In controller:

```
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'test' => '10'
    ));
```

In the form:

```
echo "test is ".$test;
```

But $test is null! I've used debugger and breakpoints and the lines in controller and form are definitely being executed. What could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: have you tried a name different with test?

Comment: Please check the view your are trying to render, I mean the path of it, the controller name and view directory name. Is everything correct? the class name of controller? the name of view? :)

Comment: I think you didn't pass it to _form.php.

Comment: @kumar_v Thank you, that is correct. Ali, thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are rendering the correct view! There is a order in Yii for rendering views, and maybe you are working in the wrong view file!